# Where did the phrase "Holy Toledo" come from?

Tags: etymology, american-english, exclamations

I was reading online and noticed this phrase in the comments.

> Holy Toledo

What is the origin of this phrase?

---

It appears in Max Shulman's 1951 collection of stories, [*The Many Loves of Dobie Gillis*](https://books.google.com/books?id=r_GdGLxwajwC&q=%22holy+toledo%22&dq=%22holy+toledo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilh8__gtPgAhWPv54KHdbVADgQ6AEIWjAJ):

> "Holy Toledo!" said Petey reverently. He plunged his hands into the raccoon coat and then his face. "Holy Toledo!" he repeated fifteen or twenty times.

But online explanations of its origin disagree, and dictionary coverage of the phrase is hard to find.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. If you are unfamiliar with Stack Exchange, please note that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and that questioners are expected to have done some preliminary research. I would suggest you edit your question to include web searches or references you might have checked, and to visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for other guidance.

Comment: This is a good question, and there is no readily available, compelling answer to it online. I've added some research to the question in hopes that site participants will reopen it.

Comment: @SvenYargs Please ask your own question if you're so interested - there's no point fixing blatantly unresearched questions.

Comment: @curiousdannii: The original question was posted in April 2014. The EL&U moderator team announced "New close reason: include the research" in December 2014. The OP last visited EL&U in December 2015. And the question was closed retroactively for insufficient research in March 2016. So the mods changed the rules for closure, and a question that had satisfied the rules when it was asked got whacked ex post facto because it didn't satisfy the new rules. Under the circumstances, I don't think it is outrageous for a current site participant to supply the retroactively claimed deficiency.

Comment: @curiousdannii No, that is not the way to go about it. If a new question had been asked, it would (should) have been closed as a duplicate of this. Fixing the original question is _precisely_ the right way to do it.

Comment: @Janus We can't read OP's mind, so we can't know why they don't know things and what research they did and didn't know. Sven wrote a detailed answer, so why didn't he put it all in the question? Because if we fix other people's posts shouldn't we fix it by doing all the research? But then there'd be no need for answers. But if we "fix" it by adding half-assed research we know is inadequate then we show our site standards are just there for keeping up appearances.

Comment: @curiousdannii I agree that the research edited into the question should have been a bit fuller, but that’s beside the point. Naturally, the first thing to do is to ask the asker to improve the question, but when (as here) the asker hasn’t been seen for five years and hasn’t responded to previous similar requests, then improving the question yourself is absolutely fine. If we use “we can’t read the poster’s mind” as a block, we’d be negating the entire concept of being able to edit posts to begin with.

Comment: @Janus So you wouldn't be opposed to me adding all the research from all the answers? What do we then close the question as? Perhaps unclear, because it's not clear what still needs to be answered? That would be dumb. We have editing powers for improving small details of posts, but we're not meant to change the substance of posts, and that includes adding research the OP never did.

Comment: @curiousdannii That is quite simply not true. Improving a question – including adding research if relevant – has been specifically recommended by mods on many occasions. The editing privileges are not only to improve small details. You’re basically saying SE has no justification at all because either a question doesn’t show enough research, or there’s nothing left to answer. There’s a huge spectrum between those two. No, adding all the research from the answers would not be OK, ‘cause it invalidates existing answers; adding “the phrase doesn’t appear in dictionaries X, Y and Z” does not.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not saying SE in general has no justification, but that ELU.SE has specific site standards which mean that only OPs should add research. But I know that many site members disagree with me. I should really argue this in Meta again.

Comment: @curiousdannii Invalidating existing answers is never valid – that’s one of the basic tenets of editing, regardless of who edits. If the asker himself edited the question to invalidate existing answers, the edit would (should) be reversed as well. But if reasonable research can be added (without invalidating any answers) and the asker is not there to do it anymore, I can see no reason not to do so, especially because there is no other way to get the question unlocked.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sometimes invalidation is necessary, but you're right that this isn't one of those times, because there's no need for questions like this to be reopened. The information's not going anywhere. It's not even like Sven wanted to added a new answer to this question, because he answered it years ago!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a humorous mock-swearword based on the taboo against blaspheming religious terms.  There are hundreds of variations on the phrase, such as "Holy Guacamole!" and "Holy Cow!"  Most of these are considered entirely non-offensive, with the exception of the best-known version, "Holy Shit!," which intensifies the taboo by combining the religious modifier with the taboo against directly referring to the fruits of the bathroom.

In the campy 60's television version of Batman, his sidekick Robin was noted for endless versions of the phrase (a habit briefly satirized in the 1997 movie "Batman and Robin").

Comment: More or less concurrent with the Batman use was a pitch for [US auto manufacturer Jeep](http://www.vintageadoftheweek.com/1967-jeepster-danny-thomas-2/): "Holy Toledo, What a Car!"  My recollection is that this ad campaign started before the Batman TV series, but the only references place it in 1967.

Comment: I'm also wondering if it were not a catch phrase for Danny Thomas, who was featured in the Jeep ad and who was a well-known TV personality at the time.  I see Thomas credited with the phrase in some references, and I recall him using it.

Answer (score 6):

What a fun question.

I could not find the origin, though the hypothesizing is amusing.

Some suggestions:

- came about because of the heavy concentration of churches located on Collingwood Boulevard (Toledo, Ohio)
- Toledo, Spain is often called “the Holy City of Toledo.”
- Holy Week has always been a bad week for show business; old-time Vaudeville actors contended that any week in Toledo was Holy Week.
- Toledoans Joe E. Brown and Danny Thomas popularized the term as they became nationally known performers (? - This makes sense)

> Another colorful possibility comes from a former policeman who joined the city police force in 1931. At that time, there was an alleged agreement between the police and underworld safecrackers (also known as box blowers and nitromen). Safecrackers would not be harassed if they would refrain from their activities in Toledo. Consequently, they could complete a job in Detroit, Cleveland or elsewhere and then retreat to Toledo - the “Holy Land.”

Searching books, the earliest I came up with was a quote from 1936:

> But in this prediction the manager was wrong, for almost as he finished speaking a great booming voice was heard in the wings. "Holy Toledo, officer, I don't savvy your lingo..."

There are indeed holy cows (India) and holy smoke (Bible). "Holy Smoke! as an expression came into use ~1870s, followed by "Holy cow!" (~1915). Perhaps out of reverence to religions, and because it flows so well, Holy Toledo (that assonance) came into being.

Joe E. Brown started in the vaudeville circuits in 1902, so... it's possible. Danny Thomas started touring in the '30s, so it's less likely that he was the first to say it if it was in print in the 30's already.

<sub>[Holy Toledo! How did it all begin?](http://www.presspublications.com/61-maumee-bay-tourist-guide/3026-holy-toledo-how-did-it-all-begin--sp-1950053719)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I found two early instances of "holy Toledo"—one from 1908 that seems to be merely coincidental with the later exclamation, and one from 1928 that seems to be the real deal. From the [*Monroe City [Missouri] Democrat*](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn90061309/1908-03-05/ed-1/seq-3/#date1=1836&index=0&rows=20&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&words=Holy+Toledo&proxdistance=5&date2=1922&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=holy+Toledo&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) (March 5, 1908):

> The Toledo Blade [a daily newspaper] says. "We would rather sit and wait two months for rosy-cheeked spring to come [to] Tintinnabulous Toledo than eat strawberries all winter in Heavenly Houston." How about preferring to pluck ice cream sodas in **Holy Toledo** during the visit of ruddy-cheeked summer than to look for a cool place in Thermogenic Houston during the same period. —Ex.

And from [*The Saturday Evening Post*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0FQkAQAAMAAJ&q=%22holy+toledo%22&dq=%22holy+toledo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi059ytyqbLAhXGsIMKHQqyCR8Q6AEIKDAC), volume 200 (1928) [combined snippets]:

> Whatever insight the adopted girl gained of her foster father's character came to her through observation—and the stars bear witness that there was plenty to observe. When he had been in regular service no one had ever noted McIntosh, engineer on 1 and 2, holding mugging parties with his oil can or stroking a polished main rod with a loving hand. He had never been known to do anything but be disagreeable and growl constantly and bring his train in on the money despite hell or high water. But when he went cut on pension, **holy Toledo**!

The instance from Thomas Johnson, [*Red War*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rKxEAAAAYAAJ&q=%22holy+toledo%22&dq=%22holy+toledo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi059ytyqbLAhXGsIMKHQqyCR8Q6AEIJDAB) (1936) that medica cites in her excellent answer is actually one of two occurrences in that book. Here they are in somewhat fuller context:

> The manager was wringing his hands, apparently on the verge of tears. "It is terrible, terrible, Herr Bayne, that this should have happened. No doubt there have been Communist riots somewhere. Alas, I fear no one will come back to see you now."
>
> But in this prediction the manager was wrong, for almost as he finished speaking a great booming voice was heard in the wings. "**Holy Toledo**, officer, I don't savvy your lingo. All I want is to ...
>
> ...
>
> "You seem to know everything, Mr. McWade."
>
> "**Holy Toledo**, I wish I did!" groaned the Westerner. "But there ain't one of us can figger out what's up—except somebody's in for a swell double crossin'."
>
> Rivers's words!

Comment: Missed this answer. Nice finds. Your ability to find the obscure always amaze me. (+1. btw.)